# Azure Cosmos DB SQL API - read/query document with unknown data structure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Cosmos DB with a container that contains document with varying structure.

I am using the Java SQL API for reading the documents from this container.

The issue I am having is that the API methods for querying/reading the container expects a model class as input param and will return instances of the model class. Because my container contains documents that have varying fields and depth, it is not possible for me to create a model class to represent this.

I need to be able to read/query the documents and then parse it myself and extract the values that I am looking for.

Any ideas? I have used "Object" in the API methods for e.g. queryItem and then it returns a LinkedHashMap that I can parse myself. Is this the way to do it? It looks a bit "raw" but I have not found a better way.

Below is a typical example from the SDK doc. I cannot create a "Family" model class in my code, because the structure can vary from document to document - both which fields are stored and the depth.

```
private void queryItems() {

        CosmosQueryRequestOptions queryOptions = new CosmosQueryRequestOptions();
        queryOptions.setQueryMetricsEnabled(true);

        CosmosPagedIterable<Family> familiesPagedIterable = container.queryItems(
            "SELECT * FROM Family WHERE Family.lastName IN ('Andersen', 'Wakefield', 'Johnson')", queryOptions, Family.class);

        familiesPagedIterable.iterableByPage(10).forEach(cosmosItemPropertiesFeedResponse -> {
            logger.info("Got a page of query result with {} items(s) and request charge of {}",
                    cosmosItemPropertiesFeedResponse.getResults().size(), cosmosItemPropertiesFeedResponse.getRequestCharge());

            logger.info("Item Ids {}", cosmosItemPropertiesFeedResponse
                .getResults()
                .stream()
                .map(Family::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Per my understanding, it's determined by the sdk funtion's input parameters and output data type. And exactly, we can find that both sample code for [java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-java-sdk-samples#query-examples) or [spring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-spring-data-sdk-samples#custom-query-examples) are depends on the data model. So it's really good for you to use Object in your code because of the various documents.

And it's true that we can't design a data model to contain all the properties in the documents but I think it's also a good idea to set a model which contains all the properties required. I mean that maybe you have a useless property in a query, so the query model should exclude it.

Comment: If you feel my post is of some help to you, could you pls accept it as the answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the proper solution:

- Create model class. Define the members with unknown depth and structure as JsonNode.

Then the model class could be used and the values of the JsonNode accessed using nice methods.